# String args[] arguments

Tags: java, string, command-line-arguments

```
class MainClass
{
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
         System.out.println("B");
     }
}
```

Normally the above code generates the output *B*. How can I Change it to `ABC` without modifying the `main()` method?

Comment: You can't, unless you pass in the value you'd like to print.

Comment: You can't.  You *could* use a static initializer to print the "A", but there's nothing you can do for the "C", AFAICS.

Comment: Why would you want to change the code without changing the code?

Comment: If you use a static initialization block you can only get `AB`

Comment: Please, provide the reasoning for this request because I'm -really- curious. What lead you to asking this? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth how to use static initializer?

Comment: "*Without modifying `main()`*" is certainly a hateful criteria. What is the reason?

Comment: I got this question as puzzle. and I was curious to solve this.

Comment: If it's a puzzle I think it should be reopened.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You can do if you override `System.out` using `System::setOut` in static initializer :)

Comment: @Gapchoos: See e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html.

Comment: @Mob: Probably not; some arbitrary constraints don't make a question that's likely to be useful to others...

Comment: This is certainly possible.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So where's the better place to ask this? Can it be moved? Because there would be really interesting posts on this.

Comment: This is how you can do it.  Since it has been closed I can't add this as an answer. https://gist.github.com/4442523

Comment: The question has been reopened, but I'm close-voting again as "too localized", for the reasons above...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thats quite OK

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public class Test
{
    static 
    {
    System.out.println("ABC");
    System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Xavier : That was really good one and simple. thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 12):

One solution is to hide `System.out` - the code below prints ABC without changing main:

```
class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

    static class System {
        static Printer out = new Printer();
    }
    static class Printer {
        public void println(String whatever) {
            java.lang.System.out.println("ABC");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its glad you replied. The accepted answer is comparatively simple.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this but its a horrible hack.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class MainClass {
    // requires Java 7 update 5+ as the internal structure of String changed.
    static {
        try {
            Field value = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
            value.setAccessible(true);
            value.set("B", value.get("ABC"));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I guess the accepted answer is much simple

Comment: @Gapchoos Technically, that solution doesn't run the code given. You could just run an unrelated class ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ugly Hack too : By using a static initialization block and setting the output stream to basically nothing.

```
package pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;


class MainClass
{
    static {
        System.out.print("ABC");
        try {
            System.setOut(new PrintStream( new OutputStream() {

                @Override
                public void write(int b) throws IOException {

                }
            }) );
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


    }
            public static void main(String []args)
            {
                     System.out.println("B");
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Trick is to override `System.out` using [`System::setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) in static initializer.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't made MainClass as public. So here is one more :

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public class SubClass extends MainClass{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println(" ABC");
   }
}
```

Save above code as SubClass.java. Subclass's main method will get called which will print **ABC** .